# Sonarqube to analyse only new lines of code- PR scan time budget to 5 minutes

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a project with very strict time budgets for SonarQube scan as part of CI pipeline. We essentially want to only scan the lines that have changed and not the full project. Is it possible to scan only changed files in the last commit, and provide report based only on changed lines of code? I want to check if added or modified lines make the project quality worst as the developer don't care about old code - only what they committed.

I saw a few notes on the Sonar Community that said this was not possible, but checking if this has changed over the past 12 months? Did not find anything in the docs.

[New Code analysis only](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/new-code-analysis-only/2916?u=agabrys)

[I want sonar analysis on newly checkin code](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/i-want-sonar-analysis-on-newly-checkin-code/9009?u=agabrys)